# Cannot assign "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, django-rest-framework, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make a request to ping my backend api with XMLHttpRequest.

Following is my code

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open("POST", 'domain:port/path/');
r.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
r.setRequestHeader("Accept", 'application/json ');

var data = {"key":"value"};

r.send(data);
```

But I always accept the following error message

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'domain:port/path/' from origin
>   'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Firstly; I think that's because I didn't set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". But even I set it, it's not working.

How can I solve my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a *response* header, not a request header.
Your *server* decides what origins are allowed to access it.  If it were that easy to bypass, would it really be a security measure? :-)
If what you truly want is for that endpoint to allow any domain to access it, then you have to add the header, there.

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)
The Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header indicates whether the response can be shared with requesting code from the given origin

it is a response header, you need to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin on your server-side code